# in Power Automate, how can I convert long-format datetime strings?

Tags: power-automate

In a Power Automate / MSFlow flow, I receive a string like this:

`Saturday, July 31, 2021 1:35 AM  |  (UTC+01:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London`

I need to convert it to the format Sharepoint expects, i.e. a ISO 8601 for UTC:

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

I painfully built a flow that does most of the work; however, at the thought of having to manually manage the timezone offset my heart finally gave out. It's shocking that in 2021 a product like this cannot parse a datetime like we could do in any language in 1995.

So my question is: what's the easiest way to parse this datetime correctly in PA/Flow...?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the MS reference:
[Workflow definition language functions reference: formatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#formatDateTime)

And the way to go was with "**formatDateTime**" function:

```
formatDateTime('<timestamp>', '<format>'?)
```

But, before that, the timestamp should be reformated in your case.
My approach will be the following:
Let's assume that the input string will be stored in a variable named **timestamp_original**.

1. Take the part before "|" character from the **timestamp_original**. and remove the Day (at the beginning) from the result.
2. pass the result to the **formatDateTime** function.
3. Use the **convertTimeZone** function to achieve the TimeZone conversion. (but this part is not working as I expected).

So the final result should be obtained by using the next expressions:

```
convertTimeZone(formatDateTime(first( split( substring(variables('timestamp_original'), add(2, indexOf(variables('timestamp_original'),','))) , '|' ) )), 'Central Europe Standard Time', 'Greenwich Standard Time')
```

The solution to the point 3, should be extracting the TimeZone from the **timestamp_original** string:

```
trim(first(split(last( split(variables('timestamp_original'), '(' ) ), ')')))
```

And add some logic to test if this TimeZone contains "UTC+" or "UTC-" and add or extract hours from the obtained timestamp.
I think you can do this.

---

It should be noted that the variable 'timestamp_original' should be initially in the next format (as the OP mentionned):

```
Saturday, July 31, 2021 1:35 AM  |  (UTC+01:00) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
```

So the result will be: (using the convertTimeZone function)

```
2021-07-30T23:35:00.0000000
```

And without using the convertTimeZone function:

```
2021-07-31T01:35:00.0000000
```

I hope this has helped. Good luck.